# UITextField value jumping to another UITextField in UITableViewCell? With video

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

To be short:
4 sections in tableview, each with 1 row, each row with a textfield.

When I enter text in the first textfield, press Done, and click one the second textfield, this text will go to the 4th textfield.

Video for this problem(only a few seconds):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T0GrCdM1PA

Source code for the uitableview:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxLbGdIIFl7KMzdlNGZlN2ItZGUwNy00OWU1LTk0M2ItY2QzMGNlNjEwNGZk&hl=en

Any comment or answer is appreciated.

xcode 3.2.6

iOS 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is assuming that each cell is used at index path for which it was created first (you are not configuring cell's content in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`). Don't reuse cells in this method if you want to store text in them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I find the solution based on your answer at:http://mobileidea.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/uitextfield_in_uitableview/ by giving each cell a different identifier.